# Creating multiple connectors in spring boot using profile

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot

According to Spring Boot documentation an application can be configured to listen on one port (**server.port**).

I want to enable multiple ports for my application, one uses SSL without client authentication and the other with (for example). The ports will be bound according to running profile of the application.

I read that this is possible to create a customized configuration for each connector and create it programmatically. I am looking for a way to reuse spring already existing configuration (address, port, ssl, etc.). In case some property defined under more than one profile the last definition will be active, a merge behavior is more suitable for my use case.

Can it be achieved with spring boot?

For example, this is a part of application.yml:

```
spring:
  profiles: profile-1

server:
  port: 8080


---
spring:
  profiles: profile-2

server:
  port: 8081
```

When the application started with **--spring.profiles.active=profile-1,profile-2** both ports (8080, 8081) will be available. According to today's implementation, the later values override earlier ones.

Comment: Just to clarify you want to have different ports in different profiles ?

Comment: I want that each profile will bind a new connector on a predefined port. In case more than one profile are active, both ports are available.